# CSS hover transform on animating element

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm trying to perform a simple CSS transform on `:hover` — which is obviously an easy task usually but I'm trying to do it on an animating div element. The element is infinitely animating on the Y axis with a simple CSS animation using `@keyframes{}`, but when I attempt to hover over the element nothing happens.

I can get it to *kind* of work if I use `!important` on the hover code, but the transform/scale happens instantly instead of using the 300ms `transition` property that I've applied to the `.box` class.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this not possible? Essentially I just want the element to scale on hover using the `transition` effect and timing, but then resume it's original animation when not hovered. Thanks

```css
.box {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid 3px #555;
  animation: box-move 1s infinite alternate-reverse;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

@keyframes box-move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">I'm a box. I move up and down, but I don't scale nicely when hovered like I should :(</div>
```

Comment: add another wrapper where you apply the scale transform

Comment: @TemaniAfif Clever idea, but for some reason this creates a weird problem with the transform origin points and it scales/moves in a strange direction which looks buggy. Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using transform property on hover and in animation both.
Try this one.

```
.box {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid 3px #555;
  animation: box-move 1s infinite alternate-reverse;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

.box:hover {
  animation: box-move-anim 1s infinite alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes box-move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
@keyframes box-move-anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-5px) scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion. But unfortunately the hover causes the new `box-move-anim` to instantly override the existing animation, causing a jerky snappy effect which looks buggy. I'm after a smoother transition. Thank you though

Comment: Its not smooth because you need to add transition in hover also. You can try. I have checked that.

Comment: Sorry but adding `transition` to the `:hover` doesn't have any effect for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Consider another wrapper:

```css
.box {
  width: 50%;
  animation: box-move 1s infinite alternate-reverse;
}
.box> div {
  border: solid 3px #555;
  transition: transform 300ms;
  transform-origin:top left;
}

.box:hover > div {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

@keyframes box-move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><div>I'm a box. I move up and down, but I don't scale nicely when hovered like I should :(</div></div>
```

Comment: Excellent solution — I was clearly missing the `transform-origin:top left` that I should've used with your previous comment to correct the problem with the transform origin points. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so thanks to your clever and helpful suggestions I managed to find a satisfactory solution. The key for me was using the `animation-direction` property set to `forwards` on the `:hover`. I can't really explain why this works but all I know that it doesn't work properly without it.

I would still ideally like the scale out (hover off) to be as smooth as the scale in (it currently just snaps back), but this will do for my needs.

Thanks again.

```css
.box {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto 0 auto;
  border: solid 3px #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: box-move 1s infinite alternate-reverse;
}

.box:hover {
  animation: box-move-anim 300ms 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes box-move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}

@keyframes box-move-anim {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">I'm a box that animates up and down, but I now smoothly scale when hovered :)</div>
```

Comment: For me this is a slightly better solution than adding another `<div>` wrapper because it doesn't require another element and is therefore slightly cleaner.